# Response not return full object after filter [Express.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have in function like this:

```
var newConvs = [];
        var tmp;

        convs.filter(function (conv) {

            tmp = conv;


            conv = conv.conversation;

            conv.reciver = tmp.reciver;
            conv.conversationId = tmp._id;

            newConvs.push(conv);
        });

        console.log(newConvs);
        res.json({
            message: newConvs
        });
```

When I `console.log(newConvs)` it return full object, but in `res.json...` I don't get this 2: `conv.reciver = tmp.reciver;
conv.conversationId = tmp._id;`

Anyone know what is reason?

Comment: You should use `map()` instead.

Comment: It return same result for me could you submit example?

Comment: So what does it return if not the full object?

Comment: It return just this part: `conv = conv.conversation;`

Comment: @Vladimir Give an example of the `convs`,  where we can see similar behavior.